# How to create a Wrapper for mapserver

Tags: wms, mapserver

I want to create a wrapper for my server. (I use mapserver and apache on windows server)

In this document ( http://mapserver.org/cgi/wrapper.html ) refer to suggestions:

1st :

```
#!/bin/sh
MAPSERV="/path/to/my/mapserv"
MS_MAPFILE="/path/to/my/mapfile.map" exec ${MAPSERV}
```

2nd :

```
#!/bin/sh
MAPSERV="/path/to/my/mapserv"
MAPFILE="/path/to/my/mapfile.map"
if [ "${REQUEST_METHOD}" = "GET" ]; then
  if [ -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ]; then
    QUERY_STRING="map=${MAPFILE}"
  else
    QUERY_STRING="map=${MAPFILE}&${QUERY_STRING}"
  fi
  exec ${MAPSERV}
else
  echo "Sorry, I only understand GET requests."
fi
exit 1
# End of Script
```

**1. Are that run on windows server?**

**2. in that document say : "Put the script in your web server’s cgi-bin directory, and make it executable". what is the name and extension of saved script ?**

also in MapServer WMS Document in url "http://mapserver.org/ogc/wfs_server.html" refer to some suggestions :

- Apache ReWrite rules (using Apache mod_rewrite)
- Apache environment variables - MS_MAPFILE
- Apache SetEnvIf
- ASP script (IIS - Microsoft Windows)
- Mapscript wrapper
- Wrapper script (Unix)

**3. Which is best suggestion? why? What are the advantages of each?**

**4. "1st suggestion" and "Apache mod_rewrite" are seems easy and good Enough. Is not it?**

Comment: I would love to get a reply for this.
Can we make an auto ip changer out of this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some php mapscript a while ago to inject a some custom information into my WMS GetCapabilities response ~ adding an extended capabilities section to make an INSPIRE compliant service, prior to that functionality becoming available natively in MapServer 6.2.

The starting point was a [MapServer for Windows (MS4W)](http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/) installation with an endpoint of for example:

http://your-server-name/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?

and an unadulterated GetCapabilities response like:

http://your-server-name/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

Take a look at the OneGeology cookbook if you want to see how to set up such a service [Step-by-step configuration for MS4W](http://www.onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/4_3_1.html).

Now with my service working (so knowing my map file had no errors) I take my php file (let's call it wms.php) like below and put it in a file location that allows php to run.

```
<?php

/*load map*/
$oMap = ms_newMapobj("D:/path/to/the/map-file/onegeology.map");s/

/*initialise request object and parse request*/
$request = ms_newowsrequestobj();
$request->loadparams();
ms_ioinstallstdouttobuffer();

/*get response from mapserver*/
$oMap->owsdispatch($request);
$contenttype = ms_iostripstdoutbuffercontenttype();

header('Content-type:' . $contenttype);

$operation = $request->getValueByName('Request');
$version = $request->getValueByName('VERSION');

/*insert inspire pieces only for version 1.3.0*/
if ((strcasecmp($version,'1.3.0') ==0 || $version == "") && strcasecmp($operation,'GetCapabilities') == 0)
{
    $content = ms_iogetstdoutbufferstring();
    $content = altercapabilities($content);
    echo $content;
}
else
  ms_iogetStdoutBufferBytes();


ms_ioresethandlers();
/************************************************************************/
/*                            altercapabilities                         */
/*                                                                      */
/*      Utility function to add the minimum requirement parts into      */
/*      a capabilities document.                                        */
/************************************************************************/
function altercapabilities($capabilities_xml)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $doc->loadXML($capabilities_xml);

    $root = $doc->documentElement;

/* ==================================================================== */
/*      add inspire name space and schema locations                     */
/* ==================================================================== */
    $doc->createAttributeNS('http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0' ,'inspire_common:inspire_common');
    $doc->createAttributeNS('http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0' ,'inspire_vs:inspire_vs');

    $root = $doc->documentElement;
    $attrs = $root->attributes;

    /*use array of attributes. getAttributeNS does not seem to return the value*/
    //$schema_value = $root->getAttribute('schemaLocation');
    foreach ($attrs as $i => $attr)
    {
        if (strstr($attr->name, 'schemaLocation'))
        {       
            $new_value = $attr->value . " http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0/inspire_vs.xsd";
            $root->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation',  $new_value);
            break;
        }
    }

/* ==================================================================== */
/*      add the extend capabilities before the Layer element.           */
/* ==================================================================== */
    $capability_node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Capability')->item(0);
    $layer_node = $capability_node->getElementsByTagName('Layer')->item(0);
    /*
    //minimum requirement 
    //a 'scenario 1' response for a service that supports only one language.
    //ref: Technical Guidance for the implementation of INSPIRE View Services v3.0
        <inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities>
            <inspire_common:MetadataUrl xsi:type="inspire_common:resourceLocatorType">               
                <inspire_common:URL>http://metadata.bgs.ac.uk/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?SERVICE=CSW&REQUEST=GetRecordById&ID=7822e848-822d-45a5-8584-56d352fd2170&elementSetName=full&OutputSchema=csw:IsoRecord&</inspire_common:URL>
                <inspire_common:MediaType>application/xml;charset=UTF-8</inspire_common:MediaType>
                //<inspire_common:MediaType>application/vnd.iso.19139+xml</inspire_common:MediaType>
            </inspire_common:MetadataUrl>
            <inspire_common:SupportedLanguages>
                <inspire_common:DefaultLanguage>
                    <inspire_common:Language>eng</inspire_common:Language>
                </inspire_common:DefaultLanguage>
            </inspire_common:SupportedLanguages>
            <inspire_com:ResponseLanguage>
                <inspire_com:Language>eng</inspire_com:Language>
            </inspire_com:ResponseLanguage>
        </inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities>
     */

    $element = $doc->createElement('inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities');
    $extend_root =$capability_node->insertBefore($element,  $layer_node);

    $metadata_url = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:MetadataUrl');
    $node_added = $extend_root->appendChild($metadata_url);

    $md_attribute = $doc->createAttribute('xsi:type');
    $metadata_url->appendChild($md_attribute);
    $md_att_text = $doc->createTextNode('inspire_common:resourceLocatorType');
    $md_attribute->appendChild($md_att_text);

    $new_node = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:URL');
    $node_tmp = $node_added->appendChild($new_node);
    $node_tmp->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('http://metadata.bgs.ac.uk/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?SERVICE=CSW&REQUEST=GetRecordById&ID=a0a82d76-657c-2a78-e044-0003ba9b0d98&elementSetName=full&OutputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&'));
    $new_node = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:MediaType');
    $node_tmp = $node_added->appendChild($new_node);
    $node_tmp->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('application/xml'));

    $supp_lan = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:SupportedLanguages');
    $node_added = $extend_root->appendChild( $supp_lan);
    $def_lan = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:DefaultLanguage');
    $node_tmp = $node_added->appendChild($def_lan);
    $new_node = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:Language');
    $node_tmp = $def_lan->appendChild($new_node);     
    $node_tmp->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('eng'));

    $response_lan = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:ResponseLanguage');
    $node_added = $extend_root->appendChild( $response_lan);
    $new_node = $doc->createElement('inspire_common:Language');
    $node_tmp = $node_added->appendChild($new_node);
    $node_tmp->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('eng'));  

    return $doc->saveXML();
}                                           
?>
```

Now we can call the service using this php file like:

http://your-server-name/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms.php?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&